# Run exe with arguments from c#

Tags: c#, process

I have referred many articles before posting this question. In my case, my exe "abc" need to pass the file name as "--run" parameter.
If I call this code from windows run window

```
c://path/abc.exe --run filename.json
```

It works but if I try to run from ProcessStart using

```
Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"c://path/abc.exe")
        {
            Arguments = "--run filename.json",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        });
```

It's not working. It just opens a window for a sec and then closes it and in the background also nothing happened.

Comment: why not using `StartInfo.Arguments` ?

Comment: Are you sure that *nothing* happened? Is the `abc.exe` looking for `filename.json`, and if so - is it started in the correct working directory?

Comment: i have updated my question, added arguments but the result is still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your filename.json located?
Have you tried setting up `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`?

Comment: json file is in same directory as of exe

Comment: it won't execute in the same directory, 10 internet points says this chap is right

Comment: But you provide full path to abc.exe. Either provide full path to filename.json or set WorkingDirectory

Comment: After adding the path to the json file , its started to work.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try passing the arguments with double quote, i.e :

```
Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(@"C://Users/source/repos/ConsoleApp5/bin folder/ConsoleApp5.exe")
        {
            Arguments = "\"--run filename.json\"",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        });
```

Looking at github for Process.cs : [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs) , it is calling [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) function which seems to use space as delimiter to pass arguments. I tried with a simple console app, and I am able to get the output as follows:

> --run filename.json